# Pass different string to activity according to user choice

Tags: android, android-activity

I have MainActivity with several buttons. User presses the button of his choice and the string from button he/she pressed is passed to second activity where it is displayed in large font. I managed to do this with my first button but I have no idea how to use all of them, so when he/she will press another button different string will be recieved by the second activity. I guess I could use switch or ifs but I dont know how to recognize on the second activity which button has been pressed. At the moment my code of the second activity looks like that:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_duza_karta);
    TextView displayZero = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bigNumber);
    displayZero.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("zero"));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this. If don't understand something feel free to ask.

```
public class ActivityA extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    public static final String TEXT_KEY = "buttontext";
    private Button buttonA, buttonB, buttonC;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundes savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.yourlayoutA); 

        buttonA = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonA);
        buttonB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonB);
        buttonC = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonC);

        buttonA.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonB.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonC.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

     public void onClick(View v) {
         String toParse = new String();

         switch(v.getId()) {
             case R.id.buttonA:
                 toParse = "button A pressed";
                  break;
             case R.id.buttonB:
                 toParse = "button B pressed";
                  break;
             case R.id.buttonC:
                 toParse = "button C pressed";
                  break;
             default:
                  break;
         }
         Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
         intent.putExtra(TEXT_KEY, toParse);
         startActivity(intent)
     }
}

public class ActivityB extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bunde savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout2);

          String toSet = getIntent().getStringExtra(ActivityA.TEXT_KEY, null);
          if(toSet != null) {
              ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.yourtextfield)).setText(toSet);
          }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thaks for quick and accurate response. I looked through your code and it looks like the solution I need. However I just wonder if I can use this code with my application or should I rewrite my code: I have declared my buttons in activity_main.xml file and assigned onClick method to those buttons. Should I remove these declarations or is it enough to delcare private Button names in mainActivity class with the same names as the xml declaration?

Comment: Of course you have to change the layout names used in my code to match your xml-files. Instead of declaring the listener for every button in your java code you can simply put an _android:onClick="onClick"_ to every button in your XML file.